# R : Is it a good practice to create a S4 class with empty slot?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I was wondering if it's a good practice to create S4 classes in R with empty slots that will be filled after with methods.

For exemple :

A class RNAseq with 3 slots: name, countMatrix and normalizedMatrix

I create the object :

`scr <-RNAseq(name=name, countMatrix= countMatrix)`

and then I use a method to fill the slot normalizedMatrix and return the object updated :

```
scr <- normalise(RNAseq)
```

I don't know if it's good practive to create an empty slot, then to fill it and at last to return the object instead of the value.

I have also an other class that inherits of RNAseq class, but all its slots are empty, and it uses the values of the mother class to fill its slots progressively , and i'm not sure for that too.

Comment: I would urge you to consider using a class that is already used by the community in this case. For example, for an 'RNA-seq' object, look into the `SummarizedExperiment` class provided by the Bioconductor Community

Comment: See documentation here: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SummarizedExperiment.html

Comment: It's just an example for my question, actually my class inherits of SummarizedExperiment class

Comment: Ok... so personally I would only return the extended class instead of the direct value if it is part of a pipeline. For example, you give your method a SumExp object, then it returns the same object and then you give that new object to another method... etc. Otherwise, it may just be less cumbersome to the user to just get the value

Comment: Okay I understand, thank you. And for the fact to create an empty slot and update it after, is it a bad practice ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on object orientation in R, but I don't think it's bad practice